# Cannot pass a pointer to a function

Tags: c++

I have removed all the unwanted segments. I am trying to pass pointers to an overloaded operator and use templates too. But this is still not working.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class Test{
      private:
             int a;
      public:
             Test (){}
             Test(int k){
                a=k;
             }
             Test* operator +(Test *p){
                  Test *temp=new Test(this->a+p->geta());
                  return temp;
             }
             int geta(){
                  return a;
             }
};

template<class T>  
   T* sum(T* a,T* b){
   return a+b;
}

int main(){
    Test *t1,*t2;
    t1=new Test(5);
    t2=new Test(7);
    Test *z=sum(t1,t2);
    cout<<z->geta();
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `t1` is a pointer, and you are calling the `add` method incorrectly - should be `t1->add(t2)`. Secondly, the `sum()` methods takes arguments which are not pointers, i.e. the template parameter is deduced as `Test` rather than `Test*`, hence you need to change the signature to something like:

```
template <typename T>
T* sum(T* a, T* b)
{
  return a->add(b); // or some variant...
}
```

Comment: Is there really any need to make it a template? As it is he is passing two ints to a perfectly good template and just adding them

Comment: @CashCow, in this instance, really no need - I was simply correcting his usage...

Comment: thanx....that t1.add was just a silly mistake...but i get wat u said abt the template...i was under the impression tht it wud include pointer references too...and i m just fooling around with templates...i dont intend to use this code segment newhr....i am a beginner u see....thanks agian....

Answer (score 1):

Who teaches people to program C++ this way? `iostream.h`??? And an overload of operator+ that takes and returns a pointer?

sum will therefore fail if you are trying to use it for Test objects. As it is, it is adding ints, not Tests.

You have a pointer so when you call add you must use -> to invoke the function, but really this is a big mess.

Comment: wats wrong wid iostream.h....and i was jus playin arnd wid templates....my first program with templates....and nobody s teachin me...

Comment: @ankur: The normal way to use `cout` is to `#include <iostream>` ... `std::cout << "etc.";`

Answer (score 0):

As Nim has already answered correctly. I will simply give some suggestions.

No need for this->a. Only a will suffice.

```
int d=a+p->geta();   
int k=sum(2,4); is again wrong as this is going to return class and not int.
```

Moreover operator+ is not right. Please learn about the reference and try to learn from some good book. This is a nice try as a first program.